# How to find the path of a file using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating a website in which I need to find out the path of the downloaded files.For instance if there is an image Image1.jpeg, downloaded and saved somewhere in the system.Is there a way through which we can find out the path of that image?

Comment: When you download a file, the cliënt is downloading the file. ASP.NET has not any information about the cliënts computer, so in other words no. If you ask a Directory.Exists for example, it will check if the Directory Exists on the server, but never on the cliënt.

Comment: Try explaining what you are attempting to do (high level) as there may be a different approach.

Comment: @TVicky..Its out of your control. The user can save the file any where on the client

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance but can we set a fixed path or a folder for the downloads to be saved ?

Comment: If you're asking this for the cliënt, than no. ASP.NET runs on the server and cannot force anything on the cliënt. Assumes that it was even possible to manage the cliënt, then you can write some code that deletes a file and when the user browses to your website, his files would be deleted. That explains why ASP.NET cannot force anything on the cliënt.

Answer (score 4):

If you mean: how to retrieve an uploaded image, the answer is: not possible. An uploaded image (or just any file) consists of a name an a list of bytes. You have to save it yourself.

If you are asking about downloaded files on the client, well, they are on the client, so outside of your control.